# Oracle CASE and BOOLEAN Numeric Expressions

Tags: sql, oracle, case, boolean-expression

Not sure why this does not work... Seems as though a >= b is a boolean expression. The RDMS is complaining about ">=3" saying "missing keyword". I followed syntax [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/case_statement.htm)

**This works:**

```
WHEN count(movie_num) 3 THEN 'Most Popular'
```

**This does not:**

```
WHEN count(movie_num) >=3 THEN 'Most Popular'
```

Probably missing something obvious so my apologies if that's the case.

**Full query**

```
select movie_genre as "Movie Genre", 
count(movie_num) as "Number of Movies",
CASE count(movie_num)
    WHEN count(movie_num) >=3 THEN 'Most Popular'
    WHEN count(movie_num) >= 2 THEN 'Popular'
    ELSE 'Normal' END AS "Popularity Rating"
from movie 
group by movie_genre
order by count(movie_num) desc;
```

Comment: You are reading the `PL/SQL` manual, not the `SQL` manual. PL/SQL and SQL are two very different languages. The CASE **expression** for SQL is documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions004.htm#SQLRF20037

Comment: `CASE count(movie_num) WHEN` ... should be `CASE WHEN`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: why CASE count(movie_num)? CASE WHEN count(movie_num) is the right way

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the PL/SQL documentation

Comment: There are two different types of `case` expression: **simple** case expression, such as `case count(movie_num) when 1 then ... when 2 then ...` and **searched** case expression, in which the word `when` follows immediately after `case` and you can have arbitrary boolean expressions in each `when`. The error in your attempt is using both forms in the same `case` expression, which obviously won't work. (It doesn't look like a typo to me, @dasblinkenlight) Beyond that, I don't believe that the first form in the post, `when count(...) 3 then`, works. That is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

changed ***CASE (movie_num) WHEN count(movie_num)*** to ***CASE WHEN count(movie_num)***

```
select movie_genre as "Movie Genre", 
count(movie_num) as "Number of Movies",
     CASE WHEN count(movie_num) >=3 THEN 'Most Popular'
          WHEN count(movie_num) >= 2 THEN 'Popular'
     ELSE 'Normal' END AS "Popularity Rating"
from movie 
group by movie_genre
order by count(movie_num) desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your conditions you could rewrite it to use [simple-case expression](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions004.htm#SQLRF20037):

```
select movie_genre as "Movie Genre", 
       count(movie_num) as "Number of Movies",
       CASE count(movie_num)
         WHEN 0 THEN 'Normal'
         WHEN 1 THEN 'Normal'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'Popular'
         ELSE 'Most Popular'
       END AS "Popularity Rating"
from movie 
group by movie_genre
order by count(movie_num) desc;
```